# How to listen a specific backend event on React app?

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, webhooks, server-sent-events

I have a react application and a flask backend. I need a simple solution for the following case, without constantly polling the backend:

- User triggers an action from React app (POST to backend)
- Backend receives the request and triggers some other service (service X), which is probably a long-running process.
- Second service gets back to backend when (if) it's done.
- Backend pushes completion notification back to React frontend.

That is, React App -> Flask EP-A -> Service X (will call back Flask EP-B when it's done)

I've investigated WebSockets and SSE (server-sent events) options. I think I need a combination of SSE and some sort of webhooks (second service calling back to flask backend when it's done).

There are two things still blurry to me here:

- In react app, I register to an endpoint on flask (e.g. /events/oncomplete) but it looks like it's continously receiving responses once I've opened a connection.
- For second service to notify backend, I need another endpoint (service X calling flask), how do I connect these two? (Service X -> Flask EP-B ->Flask EP-A -> React App)

Or should I take a different approach?

Thanks,

Comment: If not websocket (that requires some small complexity on the backend as it's not supported OOTB) you can look at EventSource.
A Flask based example here: https://gist.github.com/jelmervdl/5a9861f7298907179c20a54c0e154560

Comment: @keul I've already went through these. but all of these examples are simply based on an infinite loop pushing messages to client. this is not what I need. I need to implement something that responds back **only if a specific event occurs**

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use websockets.
For Node.js npm package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ws

Comment: I know what websockets is. Please read the problem statement before posting.